# How to correctly assign an interface to the properties of the following objects?

Tags: typescript, interface

I'm new to TypeScript, and I failed to assign an interface.

I have an array like this:

```
const data = [{ size: 1, count: 3, normal: 'one' }, { ... }]
```

Which I'm feeding to a function so I can render the data in an HTML view. I created an interface for the objects to make sure the properties are the right type:

```
function getWebviewContent(data: object[]) {
    interface Properties {
        normal: string
        count: number
    }

    return `<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Cat Coding</title>
</head>
<body>
    <ul>
    ${data.map((item: Properties) => `
        <li>${item.normal} ${item.count}</li>
    `).join('')}
    <ul>
</body>
</html>`
}
```

However, TypeScript/TSLint is throwing this error:

```
Argument of type '(item: Properties) => string' is not assignable to parameter of type '(value: object, index: number, array: object[]) => string'.
  Types of parameters 'item' and 'value' are incompatible.
    Type '{}' is missing the following properties from type 'Properties': normal, count
```

Why is this and how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your first line, you define `data` to have the type `object[]` which allows data to be an array of objects without any restrictions. But the function you then provide to data.map can only work with objects that have the properties `normal` and `count`. But `data.map`, due to the type of `data`, expects a function that can work on all objects. To solve this you should move the definition of the interface in front of your `getWebviewContent` function and change the type of the parameter of this function to `Properties[]` to ensure that only correctly typed data is passed to it.